# Expo error: ERROR Invariant Violation: ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have the following expo **error**

```
ERROR  Invariant Violation: ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.
```

Please note this is error, not a warning so I can not start my project. It doesn't show which folder the error has, but it def is not in my project it is in some of the external libraries which I use.

I tried to do a search inside `/node_modules` for `ViewPropTypes` but I got 1396 results inside 370 files. I tried to edit those who use `ViewPropTypes` from `react-native` with `deprecated-react-native-prop-types` but I still got this error so I guess there are still files which I havent edited corrctly.

My question is:

1. How, do I find all the files inside `node_modules` hich use the wrong version and edit them
2. In general, how do I fix this error. Now I can not start my project.

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/config-plugins": "^5.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.2.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.2",
    "@react-navigation/elements": "^1.3.3",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.2.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.2",
    "@react-navigation/web": "^1.0.0-alpha.9",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.0.0",
    "expo": "^46.0.0",
    "expo-av": "~12.0.4",
    "expo-blur": "~11.2.0",
    "expo-camera": "~12.5.0",
    "expo-device": "~4.3.0",
    "expo-env-info": "^1.0.5",
    "expo-file-system": "~14.1.0",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~10.4.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~13.3.1",
    "expo-image-picker-multiple": "^1.4.1",
    "expo-linking": "~3.2.4",
    "expo-location": "~14.3.0",
    "expo-media-library": "~14.2.0",
    "expo-modules-autolinking": "~0.10.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.16.1",
    "expo-permissions": "~13.2.0",
    "expo-server-sdk": "^3.6.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "expo-video-player": "^1.6.1",
    "expo-video-thumbnails": "~6.4.0",
    "firebase": "^8.2.3",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.3.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.21.2",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^6.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.9",
    "react-native-bottomsheet-reanimated": "0.0.39",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^4.0.9",
    "react-native-expo-cached-image": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-form-validator": "^0.3.5",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.1.2",
    "react-native-image-modal": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-interactable-reanimated": "0.0.15",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-map-clustering": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-maps": "0.31.1",
    "react-native-material-menu": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-mentions": "^1.1.4",
    "react-native-modalbox": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-optimized-flatlist": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-orientation": "^3.1.3",
    "react-native-pager-view": "5.4.24",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.9.2",
    "react-native-parsed-text": "0.0.22",
    "react-native-popup-dialog": "^0.18.3",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-ratings": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.9.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "github:LarvenLLC/react-native-snap-carousel",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.14.5",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-video": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-video-player": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-walkthrough-tooltip": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "rn-tooltip": "^3.0.1",
    "rne-modal-tooltip": "gist:b28c003d87c619674def0878473338a0",
    "unimodules-permissions-interface": "^6.1.0",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "eslint": "^8.17.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```